# Testing on higher/smaller resolution

Tags: testing, resolution

How can I test my website on resolution higher/lower than what my screen size could do?
Any OpenSource tools available for that or any other method ?
My primary development environment is linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Web Developer Toolbar plugin for Firefox. You can define custom resolutions and basically the window is adjusted to what you select.

Comment: any browser independent tool ?

Comment: This is the only one I worked. I usually design fixed width pages.